# Stored Procedure doesn't return any result as output but query works fine

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Why this stored procedure doesn't return any result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_location_selectAllByTermAutoComplete`(
IN _term VARCHAR(99))
BEGIN

    SELECT
        `title` AS `value`,
        `keyword` AS `label`,
        `city_id`,
        `id` AS `locationtitle_id`
    FROM `locationtitle`
    WHERE
        MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST(_term  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST(_term  IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
;END//
```

But this one returned

```
    SELECT
        `title` AS `value`,
        `keyword` AS `label`,
        `city_id`,
        `id` AS `locationtitle_id`
    FROM `locationtitle`
    WHERE
        MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST('+NEW*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST('+NEW*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

Both of the input parameters are same as other.

I have other stored procedure and they works fine.

I'm using `PDO` to execute my stored procedure.

I never used `OUT` in my stored procedure and no experience how to use it.

I have tested the stored procedure in my localhost and works fine, but i don't know why it doesn't works on my server?

**UPDATE**

I found my what is my problem.

When i call a procedure that have `VARCHAR` as input parameter, string characters change to `?` (question sign).

My database collation is **UTF-8** and any table are too

And i added pdo utf-8 driver but i don't know why it doesn't work

Even i cant call stored procedure in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade to set database collation utf8 before import or insert any characters.

Now, I set my database collation to utf8 and then import my data again. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say, but I would try this to check if data types, quotes etc. are as you expect them to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_location_selectAllByTermAutoComplete`(
IN _term VARCHAR(99))
BEGIN

    SELECT
        _term as my_param,
        MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST(_term  IN BOOLEAN MODE) as my_param_result,
        `title` AS `value`,
        `keyword` AS `label`,
        `city_id`,
        `id` AS `locationtitle_id`
    FROM `locationtitle`
    WHERE
        MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST('+NEW*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY MATCH(`keyword`) AGAINST('+NEW*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
;END//
```

and then pass in

> '+NEW*

' as your parameter.

Comment: I found what is my problem but i don't know how to solve it. I changed my question.